# Page cannot be displayed message for SP App when deployed using App Catalog

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, deployment, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am trying to deploy a SharePoint Hosted App on my development machine by packaging it and uploading in app catalog. When the app is deployed directly using visual studio,it works fine. But when I upload the app using app catalog and add it to a site,clicking the app gives message:

> "Page cannot be displayed"

Any idea why this is happening? App Domain and App catalog URL is configured properly.

**Update**:

While deploying using app catalog, entries are not added to host file.

Manually adding the app domain entries resolves the issue.

**Is there any permanent fix for this so that i don't have to manually add the entries?**

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with the DNS. When you deploy from Visual Studio it automatically adds the appropriate DNS entries to the Hosts file.

When you deploy by uploading to the App Catalog that entry in the host file is not created.

Configure the app domain so that everyone can access pages in the app domain. This involves setting up the app domain in DNS and creating a forward lookup zone and a CNAME alias

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already configured the app domain using the given method and the app url is properly created.  I ll check by adding it manually in the host file.

Comment: You may also need to configure your network adapter to ensure it uses the local DNS first. I generally have my Preferred DNS Server set to 127.0.0.1 and my secondary DNS Server set to 4.2.2.4